# which library is used for StreamWriter in C++ window forms?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

```
public ref class form : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:

    form(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        void save(String^ word);

    }
    //windows form generated code
    ...
    ...
    ...
    void save(String^ word)
    {
        StreamWriter^ outFile = gcnew StreamWriter("file.txt");
        outFile->WriteLine(word);
        outFile->Close();
    }
    #pragma endregion

private:

    System::Void button00_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        String^ word = "PLOW";
        save(word);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) does not belong to Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1):

StreamWriter resides in the namespace System::IO and is implemented in mscorlib.dll. Simply add the line

`using namespace System::IO`

to the imports of your code file and you are ready to go.

Comment: i want header file like     #include"stdafx.h".

Comment: using visual studio 2015

Comment: As this is a class of the .net framework, there are no header files. Instead there are namespaces. Use the above line exactly like you would use an include statement. Just be sure to add a reference to the .net assembly "System" (this is mscorlib.dll) in your project.